# Detect computers connected on network via android java

Tags: java, android, sockets, windows-services

I'm writing an Android app to communicate with a Windows service over socket connections. 
The code is working but I want to add the ability to detect devices connected on local network so the app can determine which computer is running the windows service I want, I'm using the code below which I got from this website too. My issue is the code below only detects android devices and doesn't detect my laptop. I can ping my device from my laptop and ping my laptop from my device, so what to do from here?

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet) {
    int timeout = 1000;
    for (int i = 1; i < 254; i++) {
        String host = subnet + "." + i;
        try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {

                System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                System.out.println("Host Name: "
                        + InetAddress.getByName(host).getHostName());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone I ended up creating a socket connection to each IP in the network and displaying host name from the socket. it showed me all devices whether they are android devices or windows machines.

Of course since I made the socket listen at port 8000 on both device and computer, so using a socket will give result IF AND ONLY IF both ends are listening on the same port, and I only care about computers that are running my service.

I really appreciate all the suggestions and help :)

Answer (score 2):

InetAddress.isReachable() is not very reliable. 
If ICMP messages are blocked you won't get an answer.

What you could do is sending a broadcast message.
Your server application has to listen for this message and answer it.
This way you get the server IP address and you can connect to it.
And you have to send only one message to reach all hosts in the subnet.

[Example code for sending and receiving broadcast messages](https://lab.dyne.org/AndroidUDPBroadcast)

Comment: His answer is right but the link is messed up. Try this http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html -- It applies for Android's java as well with a caveat, you need to acquire an instance of this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html